# How to run a java spark project on AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have a java spark project in which, i simply want to read data from S3 and also write it in S3, but i came to that AWS glue does not support java, so i decided to write a wrapper in scala the code is given below :-

```
package com.example.app
import com.example.Main

object App {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       println("Hello world!")
       Main.main(args)
       println("done")
   }
}
```

and there build.sbt file contains :

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
.settings(
name := "scala-wrapper-javaRW",
idePackagePrefix := Some("com.example.app"),
assembly / mainClass := Some("com.example.app.App"),
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = true, includeDependency = true)
)

dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.example" % "javaRW" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" from "file:/home//javaRW/target/javaRW-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

And my java program is :-

```
package com.steerwise;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
        String location = args[0];
        String outputPath = args[1];
        Dataset<Row> dataset =spark.read()
                .option("header", true)
                .option("sep", "'")
                .option("delimiter", "\"")
                .csv(location);
        dataset.show();

        Dataset<Row> d1 = dataset.limit(10);
        d1.write()
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .option("header", true)
                .csv(outputPath);
    }
}
```

But when i run it on AWS glue it start throwing a lots of errors :

```
2023-05-10 11:46:54,376 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(77)): InvocationTargetException java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2023-05-10 11:46:54,401 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(98)): Exception in User Class
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Multiple sources found for csv (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.csv.CSVDataSourceV2, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat),
 please specify the fully qualified class name.
at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.findMultipleDataSourceError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:1083) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:702) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:725) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:207) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:185) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at GlueApp$.main(testRW.scala:44) ~[testRW.scala.jar:?]
at GlueApp.main(testRW.scala) ~[testRW.scala.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:50) ~[AWSGlueSparkResourceManager-1.0.jar:?]
```